# Switching between two css sheet - Google Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-extension

Here is the problem: I am building a Google Chrome extension and I would like the user to choose between 2 content scripts designs (2 css files). So far, I found two solution:

1) using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(integer tabId, InjectDetails details, function callback)
```

2) Changing the css style only with javascript.

I would like to know which one is the best practice. Though modifying everything in javascript seems a little crazy :p. Of course if you have a 3d and better solution that would be great.

Comment: Actually first method would be wrong if you have similar classnames / ids etc :) It could cause colision. You should dynamically load needed <link> tag using javascript and remove the old one.

Comment: I tried :
    `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+chrome.extension.getURL("customStyles/StyleA.css" )+'" type="text/css" />');`
but I get this error : 
Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Comment: You must add web_accessible_resources to your manifest.json first. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something with this:

```
<link class='mystyle' href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Giving the link tag a class name makes it possible to change the href property with jQuery.

```
$(".mystyle").prop("href", "style2.css");
```

I ran a quick test on a single div element and it seems to work fine.

Work it into a statement:

```
if ( choosestyle1 == true) {
       $(".mystyle").prop("href", "style1.css");
} else {
       $(".mystyle").prop("href", "style2.css");
}
```

Preload stylesheets:

```
var stylesheets = Array("style1.css", "style2.css");
stylesheets.forEach(function(arg){
    $("<div />").load(arg);
});
```

Comment: It works fine but it takes time before the css is loaded. When I use `"css": ["mystyleA.css"],` the css file is loaded before de html page. It's a pity you can not choose in the manifest file :p

Comment: If you want to prevent loading time on the user action, you may want to preload the stylesheets as the page loads. I added the preload to the example. If it works, i don't know, but I do know the stylesheets get loaded into the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Paul I don't know much about developing Chrome extensions but for `HTML`  basic idea is to tells the browser about current CSS.

you would have to set a `coockie` through javascript that tells the page which `CSS` to be used, and whenever you switch to the other `CSS`, modify the cookie.

Please refer to this link, here's a [demo download](http://languagelassi.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-switch-between-two-css-files-on-a-page.html)